# Querying SQL column varchar6 containing numbers with a between statement

Tags: sql, select, syntax, varchar, between

The table has a column that is type varchar6 containing 6 numbers between 000000 to 999999, or is empty.
No matter what values you give the various variables for this column SEQ, it keeps returning no results but no syntax errors.
I suspect you can't find anything in SQL if you do a between with two varchar6's.

The sql query is;

```
select Top 2000 A.* 
from TABLE1 A 
where A.SEQ between '0' and '999999'
```

This feels like a design flaw because storing and comparing numbers probably shouldn't be using varchar6 but Changing the design of the table is unfortunately out of the question.

How do I change this SQL so that it does compare properly?

Comment: Between on a varchar field compares ASCII characters not numbers. Ie, 12 is between 1 and 2. Can you cast them to ints?

Comment: Like this?

select Top 2000 A.* 
from TABLE1 A 
where (int,A.SEQUENCE_NO) between '1' and '999999'

Comment: @Kuei. . . You code should work.  Something else is wrong, such as a leading character that you cannot see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work.  I suspect you have a problem with the data.  You can check with:

```
select A.* 
from TABLE1 A 
where try_convert(int, A.SEQ) is null and A.SEQ is not null;
```

Or:

```
select A.* 
from TABLE1 A 
where A.seq like '%[^0-9]%';
```

When you find the problem with the data, you can fix the issue.  You will also learn why you should NOT store numbers in a string.

Comment: I think there's a typo in the regex for the second example. If the intent is to find strings that contain non-digit characters, it currently only finds strings that don't start with a digit. E.g. it matches 'A12' but not '1AB'. It needs to be '%[^0-9]%' to match non-digits anywhere in the string.

Comment: @WileCau . . . I think you're right.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah turns out there's random spaces in the data so " 00    " wasn't matching properly. Thank you for the regex idea.

Answer (score 0):

You said the string is VARCHAR(6) and you want to select anything between 0-999999, so that seems to be anything numeric.

You can select the numeric values like this:

```
SELECT TOP 2000 *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ISNUMERIC(SEQ) = 1
```

Or if you know there are only numeric strings and blanks (I assume by blank you mean NULL or ''), you could select the non-blanks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 2000 *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE SEQ IS NOT NULL AND SEQ <> ''
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is what I was looking for, thank you!